# Pandas DataFrame check with Whitelist

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I have a whitelist.csv file with data like following.

```
IP Name
66.249.72.105 GOOGLE
66.249.72.111 GOOGLE
157.55.32.103 MSN
```

And I have a large pandas `DataFrame` "DF" with data.

```
IP            User-Agent                                           Name
157.55.32.100 msnbot-media/1.1 (+http://search.msn.com/msnbot.htm) MSN
66.249.72.111 Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html) GOOGLE
173.0.53.160 Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0 VIRPUS
```

What I'm trying is to find who are in the white-list from "DF". So I need to check IP and Name. But if the Name is in DF and IP is not in Whitelist I need to add it to whitelist.

```
DF2 = (if IP&Name or Name is in whitelist)
    If only name is in whitelist but not IP add it in to whitelist.csv.
```

For exmple in the given DataFrame **MSN** is there but **157.55.32.100** is not in whitelist.csv. So I need to add it. Resulting **DF2** should be something like:

```
    IP            User-Agent                                           Name
157.55.32.100 msnbot-media/1.1 (+http://search.msn.com/msnbot.htm) MSN
66.249.72.111 Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html) GOOGLE
```

I tried merging but how to add the IPs not available in Whitelist?. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want:

```
In [9]:
df.merge(df1, on=['Name','IP'], how='outer')
Out[9]:
              IP    Name                                         User-Agent
0  66.249.72.105  GOOGLE                                                NaN
1  66.249.72.111  GOOGLE  'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http...
2  157.55.32.103     MSN                                                NaN
3  157.55.32.100     MSN  'msnbot-media/1.1 (+http://search.msn.com/msnb...
4   173.0.53.160  VIRPUS  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:21.0) Gecko/2...
```

You could drop the `NaN` rows if they are surplus but I would think you would want to keep the rows as you have a different IP address.

Comment: Do want to overwrite the csv or append the new entries?

Comment: I'll say like this, here GOOGLE,MSN are only in the whitelist. In my "DF" also GOOGLE,MSN is there and a new IP for MSN. I need to add this new IP to Whitelist?

Comment: On your sample data this would result in MSN and VIRPUS as the new IP addresses, is that what you want? you could do `df2 = df.merge(df1, on=['Name','IP'], how='outer') df2[~(df2['IP'].isin(df['IP']))]`